# How to Move a Stored Procedure in Oracle SQL from one Schema to Another?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to understand what steps I need to undertake in order to move a stored procedure from one schema and into another. The schema that this is currently sitting in is going to be made redundant and I have been asked to move all tables and procedures. I have no trouble with tables but never done anything with procedures hence want to make sure I don't miss anything out.

What I have currently done is look through the procedure and made a list of what its actually doing i.e. dropping/creating and inserting data into tables.

After this I wasn't sure if it was just a case of copying the procedure code and then creating a new procedure on the new schema with the same code and then compiling it.

I would really appreciate it if somebody could advise if I am missing anything in the steps that I am undertaking just to ensure I don't mess things up.

Comment: It is literally what you described: "just a case of copying the procedure code and then creating a new procedure on the new schema with the same code and then compiling it". The biggest thing to watch for in the code is embedded schema names on references to other database objects like tables or other procedures. Any names referring to the old schema would have to be changed or removed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "move" an object from one schema to another.

The only practible way I see here is copying the source code and then executing it in the new schema. As @pmdba wrote as comment, you should watch out for schema names like "MYSCHEMA"."TABLENAME" and other references.

If you got too much to copy you may consider writing a block where you automatically read the data of the old schema and create it automatically in the new one.
You can get the data of (nearly) everything with, i.e. procedures:

```
select * from all_source where owner = 'OLDSCHEMANAME' and type = 'PROCEDURE';
```

and use it like this:

```
begin
    ....
    select listagg(text, '') within group (order by line) into proc_code
    from all_source
    where owner = 'OLDSCHEMANAME'
        and type = 'PROCEDURE'
    group by name;

    execute immediate 'create or replace ' || proc_code; -- perhaps you need to remove the last ';' here
    ...
end;
```

Please note that this code is only meant as hint and doesn't need to be taken exactly that way. Also, you may still get errors due to non existing objects, wrong schema references etc..

To get the ddl of a table one may use `select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','Table_name','Schema_Name') from dual;`.
By [googling dbms_metadata.get_ddl](https://www.google.com/search?q=oracle%20dbms_metadata.get_ddl) you might get more info on the DBMS_METADATA-package and how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, there is no mechanism to copy one object ( procedure , function or package, etc ) to another schema. One alternative is using all_source, but I prefer **DBMS_METADATA** because allows you to transfer all dependencies, like for example privileges. Imagine I need to copy a procedure but I need to keep the privileges, with this package I can get everything.

Example

```
SQL> create procedure myschema1.my_procedure ( p1 number )
  2  as
  3  var1 number := p1;
  4  begin
  5  select 1 into var1 from dual;
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL> grant execute on myschema1.my_procedure to myuser ;

Grant succeeded.
```

Now, let's imagine we want to copy the procedure and its privileges to another schema

```
SQL> set long 99999999 set lines 200 pages 400
SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROCEDURE','MY_PROCEDURE','MYSCHEMA1') from dual ;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('PROCEDURE','MY_PROCEDURE','MYSCHEMA1')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE PROCEDURE "MYSCHEMA1"."MY_PROCEDURE" ( p1 number )
   as
var1 number := p1;
begin
select 1 into var1 from dual;
end;
```

But, imagine you don't want quotation and neither the editionable argument

```
SQL> select 
replace(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROCEDURE','MY_PROCEDURE','MYSCHEMA1','11.2.0'),'"','') as ddl from dual ;

DDL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYSCHEMA1.MY_PROCEDURE ( p1 number )
as
var1 number := p1;
begin
select 1 into var1 from dual;
end;
```

Then to get the final command with the new schema owner, we use regexp_replace to replace the first occurrence

```
SQL> select regexp_replace(replace(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROCEDURE','MY_PROCEDURE','MYSCHEMA1','11.2.0'),'"',''),'MYSCHEMA1','MYSCHEMA2',1,1)
  2  as ddl from dual ;

DDL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYSCHEMA2.MY_PROCEDURE ( p1 number )
as
var1 number := p1;
begin
select 1 into var1 from dual;
end;
```

Finally, we can get all privileges by

```
SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl( 'OBJECT_GRANT' , 'MY_PROCEDURE' , 'MYSCHEMA1' ) from dual ;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DEPENDENT_DDL('OBJECT_GRANT','MY_PROCEDURE','MYSCHEMA1')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  GRANT EXECUTE ON "MYSCHEMA1"."MY_PROCEDURE" TO "MYUSER"
```

Remember to apply at session level before to start some settings to enhance dbms_metadata output:

```
begin
  DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'SQLTERMINATOR', true);
  DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param (DBMS_METADATA.session_transform, 'PRETTY', true);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you all for your concise explanations, will go through it all.

Comment: @MichaelOwen, if you consider, may you upvote the answer ? later on when you have more answers you can accept the one you consider